# SQLAlchemy hybrid_method - Passing Obvious Argument

Tags: methods, sqlalchemy

I am working with python and sqlalchemy. I have one table named Team and another named Game.  The Game table has columns "away_id" and "home_id" and the Team table has the column "team_id".  I just made this hybrid_method for the Team class which will return all game instances where the away_id, or home_id matches the team_id.  The argument I pass it, s, is a session instance.  How can I write this code as a @hybrid_property where I don't have to pass it a session instance?

```
@hybrid_method
def games(self, s):
    return s.query(Game).filter(or_(Game.away_id==self.team_id, Game.home_id==self.team_id)).all()
```

Answer (score 1):

First off, from what I can see here this is not a use case for "@hybrid"  hybrid is used for specifically the use case where you'd like to say:  "MyClass.games == something", at the class level, as well as, "my_object.games == something", at the instance level.  That is not the case here, you're trying to run a query in its entirety, passing a specific `self.team_id` into it - so you need a `self`, so this is just a regular method or descriptor.

So just use @property with object_session() as the docs [say right here](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_8/orm/mapper_config.html#using-a-plain-descriptor):

```
class MyClass(Base):
   # ...

   @property
   return object_session(self).query(Game).filter(...)
```